# How to show $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{Q(x_k)}{P'(x_k)(x-x_k)}$ when the following condition holds?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with n different real roots 
$x_1,x_2,....x_n$ and let $Q$ be a polynomial of degree at most $n -1$. How to  Show 
that

$ \ \ \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{Q(x_k)}{P'(x_k)(x-x_k)}$

Comment: By all means, please include what you know about the questions you ask (here, about the decomposition of rational fractions). As your question is, potential answerers must guess your level of mathematical knowledge before answering. Since you seem to like caps, let me mention this is UNCOOL.

Comment: What you wrote is not correct. Check for typos.

Answer (score 2):

Your typo is that the LHS should be $ Q(x)/P(x) $, it is easy to observe that $ x_1,...,x_n $ being roots of $P$ you have always 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_j} \frac{P(x)}{(x-x_k)} = P'(x_j)\delta_{jk} $$
Now look at the ploynomial $ F \in \mathbb{R}[X] $ given by the following (which is indeed a polynomial as $ (x-x_k)\  |\ P(x) $ )
$$ F(x) = \sum_k \frac{Q(x_k)P(x)}{P'(x_k)(x-x_k)} $$
Clearly from the behavior of limit as shown above you find that $ F(x_j) = Q(x_j) $, that is $ x_1, x_2,...,x_n $ are roots of $ F- Q $, but as $ \deg(P) = n $ so we have $ \deg(Q) \leq n-1 = \deg (F) $, so $\deg(F-Q)\leq n-1 $, but it has n roots, hence $ F = Q $ which implies 
$$ \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_k \frac{Q(x_k)}{P'(x_k)(x-x_k)} $$

Comment: @ROBINSON If you are convinced, do you mind ticking to accept this as an answer ?